# Upgrade Git-Lab on Air-gapped Environment (offline)

Tags: git, gitlab, upgrade, offline, rhel8

I'm unable to upgrade my gitlab to the latest version.

Hi All,
I've installed and configured GitLab in a air-gapped (offline) environment using rpm which is running on rhel 8.5. Due to some vulnerability issue, we need to upgrade Git-lab to a specific version. for that I've download the rpm package from the below location and uploaded to the environment.
`https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/el/8/gitlab-ce-15.6.1-ce.0.el8.x86_64.rpm`

After that I've tried to update the existing gitlab with the newly uploaded rpm file using the command `rpm -i <package-name>` .
Even though I didn't get any error messages but still my gitlab has the same version.

Best Regards,
Gulam Moideen

Comment: Have you tried to restart `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` ? What do you get with `sudo gitlab-ctl status` ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, Yeah I've tried with restart and verified the status of Gitlab with gitlab-ctl status cmd. After that also Gitlab still has the older version.